# Не редактируются .cshtml-файлы

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc

После обновления VS 2017 Community Edition перестали редактироваться View-файлы (формата cshtml). Все остальные файлы редактируются как надо. А при вводе текста в cshtml ничего не меняется. Причём их никак не возможно отредактировать. Комбинации клавиш и контекстного меню также не работают